# How to prevent responsive menu closing all my nav?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, nav

responsive menu issue.

When you view the menu at below 800px and press the grey btn you are shown a dropdown menu.

You should be able to see I have "login and JOin" btns positioned absolutely top right.

The problem occurs once you close the nav, it also closes the top right btns. I want these btns to remain where they are. !

Here is my working fiddle. Would love the help !!!
http://jsfiddle.net/y5N6S/2/

```
li{
list-style: none;
}
a:link, a:visited{
color: #4083a9;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 13px;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: #205f82;
}
ul, ol, h1, h2, h3, h4, p{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;;
}
p{
line-height: 22px;
font-size: 13px;
}

.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}
img:hover{
  opacity: .7;
}
/* =============================================================================
   HEADER
   ========================================================================== */

#header{
      width: 100%;
      height: 67px;
      background: white;
      z-index: 9997;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
    }
      #header-inner{
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 12px;
        max-width: 970px;
      }
        #logo{
          float: left;
          padding: 0px 20px 0 0;
        }
          #logo a{
            display: block;
            width: 107px;
            height: 50px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0 50%;
            background-image: url(../img/home/oh-holla.png);
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
            -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
            transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
            }

             #logo img{
              height: 0;
             }

              #logo a:hover{
               opacity: .6;
             }

              #nav{
                margin: 1px 0px 0 0px;
                color: #777;
                padding:0px;
                float:right;
                display:block;
              }
                #nav>li{
                  float: right;
                  font-size: 1.25em;
                  line-height: 1;
                  margin-left: 30px;
                }
                  #nav>li>a{
                      display: block;
                      height: 66px;
                      line-height: 66px;
                      text-decoration: none;
                      color: #333;
                      font-weight: bold;
                  }

                    #toggle-nav{
                      display: none;
                    }




 /* =============================================================================
  NAVIGATION MEDIA MAX 800PX
   ========================================================================== */
                    @media screen and (max-width: 800px){

                    #header{
                        position: fixed;
                        height: 57px;
                    }

                      #toggle-nav{
                          position: absolute;
                          top: 0;
                          left: 0px;
                          display:block;
                          width: 48px;
                          height: 40px;
                          text-indent: -9999px;
                          background-repeat: no-repeat;
                          background-position: 15px 50%;
                          opacity: .5;
                            background:black;
                        }

                        #logo a{
                          display: block;
                          height: 40px;
                          margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
                        }

                          #logo{
                            float: none;
                            padding-right: 0;
                            text-align: left;
                          }
                            #nav{
                            float: left;
                            width: 100%;
                            margin: 0 0 10px 0;
                            text-align: left;
                            display:none;

                            }
                            #nav li{
                              position: relative;
                              float: none;
                              margin-right: 0;
                              text-align: left;
                              font-size: 12px;
                              background: #323232;
                              margin-left: 0px;
                            }
                            #nav li:hover{
                              background: #2e2e2e;
                            }
                            #header-inner{
                                width: auto;
                                padding: 0;
                            }
                            #nav li a{
                              height: auto;
                              padding: 15px;
                              font-size: 14px;
                              font-weight: bold;
                              line-height: 1;
                              border-top: 1px solid black;
                              background: white;
                            }
                            #wrap-inner{
                              padding-top: 60px;

                            }
                            li#join{
                              display: block;
                              float: none;
                              position: absolute;
                              top: 0;
                              right: 0;
                              background: none;
                            }
                            li#signin{
                              display: block;
                              float: none;
                              position: absolute;
                              top: 0;
                              right: 70px;
                              background: none;
                            }

                    }
```

Comment: You cant have them inside of your nav list or else they will get hidden when you hide it. Youre going to have to restructure your HTML so they are elsewhere

Comment: Here is a fiddle with a working answer, you can't have the links inside of the `ul` that is being toggled. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/y5N6S/6/

Comment: Thanks for you help. There seems to be a bug,,once you open and close the media queries nav and then open the page above 800px the main nav is not showing.??

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:none` to `#nav li` as opposed to `#nav`, then use the following updated jQuery..

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/y5N6S/5/) - it works!

```
$("#toggle-nav").click(function () {
    $("#nav li:not(#signin):not(#join)").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Doing this won't require an HTML changes, thus it will still work in the other responsive media query!

Answer (score 0):

Switch the html to:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
            <li id="join"><a href="#">Join</a></li>
            <li id="signin"><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
    </ul>
      <div id="header-inner">
        <div id="logo">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/home/oh-holla.png" alt="Chartego Logo"/></a>
        </div>
        <a href="#toggle-nav" id="toggle-nav">Toggle navigation</a>

        <ul id="nav">
            <li id="discover"><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
            <li id="charts"><a href="#">Charts</a></li>
            <li id="livefeed"><a href="#">Livefeed</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!--end of header-->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y5N6S/4/

You'll need to correct the CSS a bit to make the join/sign in links look right again but they in the upper corner all the time in the above fiddle.